# See, my nose is running."

Tags: grammar

He has a runny nose.

He pointed his nose and said,

**"See, my nose is running."**

Can running use as above? Or there is another way to say the situation above.

Comment: I might use "Look" here rather than "See" as the initial interjection.  Both are correct, but "See" is used either as a meaningless conversational filler or to say "see, you may have been sceptical or doubtful, but here's the evidence".  "Look" is used to ask someone to look in a particular place or at a particular thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with that.

> "If your nose runs and your feet smell, you've been built upside-down." Spike Milligan (Irish comedian, 1918-2002)